# PostgreSQL update query performance issue

Tags: postgresql

I am not familiar with PostgreSQL. I found this query

```sql
UPDATE theater_visitor
SET viewer_total_count = viewer_total_count + 1
WHERE movie_id = $1
```

Let's consider this. 100+ users start watching at the same time, 100+ request will come at the same time, how postgresql server will behave?

I personally think, this design can be improved, considering some queuing mechanism to reduce the write rate, what other issue should I be concerned with?

Comment: 100+ users is nothing, and there is not going to be a performance issue with the code you've posted. Expand that to 100,000 that start at **exactly** the same time, and it might be an issue. Don't work on premature optimization. Let the DBMS do its job, and when you start getting performance problems, you can use the query execution plan to find out where the bottleneck is and working on fixing it.

Comment: @KenWhite, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

If the 100 users watch different movies, they will be updated in parallel. If they all watch the same movie, the updates will be serialized automatically. Since locks are held until the end of the database transaction, it is important that you keep that transaction as short as possible.

Comment: Thanks, concern point is input on same movie. 100+ is a poor example. Expectation, 10000+ activity in single stream. Your input is helpful.

Comment: "Stream"? Not sure what you mean.